# Why Code doesn't provide access to write to dataset even after giving permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

[code screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX7Vx.png)

[code screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKW6A.png)

I want to read a data set table in on project big query to write in another 
project data set in other table but it is working with all users big query data editor role but not with my first project service account with same role

I want to read a data set table in on project big query to write in another 
project data set in other table but it is working with all users big query data editor role but not with my first project service account with same role    I want to read a data set table in on project big query to write in another 
project data set in other table but it is working with all users big query data editor role but not with my first project service account with same role

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your code should be on Stack Overflow not in a linked image. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question, write your code in the question insted sharing an snapshot of it. Also format your question properly.